# Where I can find all the DataAnnotations error keys for localization?

Tags: asp.net-core, localization

I want to localize my application for Russian.

I have this model (simplified):

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "RangeError")] // - this translates fine
    public int? PremiseArea { get; set; }
}
```

I have .resx file with my custom localization strings and when I enter 200 in input, the error shows in Russian, as I want.
My problem is when I'm entering letters in the input. I get this error:

[image: Please enter a valid number.]

How to handle these errors? Where to find the list of all the DataAnnotations errors by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Please enter a valid number.' this format looks like a default **jquery validation message**.

How did you apply the validation?

You can also directly **define the validation message in javascript**,and then localize the
validation

message, as my following demo. And this is [jquery validation documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').validate({ 
            rules: {
                PremiseArea: {    //rule the number and range
                    number: true,
                    range: (1, 100)
                }
            },
            messages: {
                PremiseArea: {
                    number:"@Localizer["Please enter a valid number."]",  //localize the message
                    range: "@Localizer["Range Error"]"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! Indeed, the problem was on the client-side. I solved it by including this code in my project https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/localization/messages_ru.js

Answer (score 1):

There are different type of validation error messages.

- Data annotations validation errors
- Model binding validation errors
- Identity describer validation errors
- Custom validation error messages

Additionally, there are [browser form validation errors](https://intopia.digital/articles/default-browser-error-messages/) that depends on the field type, and you can override those errors by configuring client side validation.

Each of them requires different approach to be localized.

- Data annotation localization:
  [ASP.Net core multilingual validation messages for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558643/asp-net-core-multilingual-validation-messages-for-forms)
- Model Binding Errors Localization:
  [ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization/64681729#64681729)
- Identity Errors Localization:
  [How to translate Identity Password validation messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566451/how-to-translate-identity-password-validation-messages/53587825#53587825)
- Custom Validation Errors Localization:
  [ASP.NET Core custom validation error message not localized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776877/asp-net-core-custom-validation-error-message-not-localized)

You can read these articles to learn more about localization in depth:

- [Developing Multicultural Web Application](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application)
- [Localizing Data Annotations Errors](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/16-Localizing_Data_Annotations)
- [Localizing Model Binding Errors](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/18-Localizing_ModelBinding_Error_Messages)
- [Localizing Identity Error Messages](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/20-Localizing_Identity_Errors)

#### Last but not least:

Configuring all localization settings takes a lot of time and effort, if you want to do it faster I suggest using [XLocalizer](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer), it does all settings in simple setup in the startup, additionlly it can do online translation and auto adding for the localizable strings, so you don't fill resources manually, see the [docs for more details](https://docs.ziyad.info).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found some interesting things from the links that you attached